# Set updated state props on button click using redux

Tags: react-native, redux

I am trying to create a button which is displaying and hiding a navigation menu on click. I am using Redux to get the current state into the Component, but something is not working with the onPress function.
When pressing the button I want to check the current state of this.state.showNavigation (can be true/false) but I am getting an "undefined is not an object" error immediately after clicking the button.

I think I am running into a lifecycle issue here. I already tried to ship around this via setting the state in componentWillMount like that:

```
componentWillUpdate(){
    this.state = NavigationStore.getState();
}
```

Anyway that didn't help. Some advise is much appreciated. Thanks!
Heres my code:

```
class NavigationButton extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.state = NavigationStore.getState();
        NavigationStore.subscribe(() => {
            this.setState(NavigationStore.getState());
        });
        // alert(this.state.showNavigation);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.handlePressButton}
                style={navigationButtonStyles.button}>

                <Image source={buttonImage} />

            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

    handlePressButton() {
        if(this.state.showNavigation){
            NavigationStore.dispatch({
                type: 'HIDE_NAVIGATION',
            });
        }
        else{
            NavigationStore.dispatch({
                type: 'SHOW_NAVIGATION',
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It is not enough info to solve your problem but at least I can point you on few problems:
1. never mutate state directly `this.state = NavigationStore.getState()`. Use `this.setState` instead
2. do not set state in `componentWillUpdate`. use other lifecycle methods for that.
3. try to use `connect` function from Redux at least for beginning
4. `navigationButtonStyles` is not defined anyware

Answer (score 0):

I was using a pretty strange approach, I did not use the react-redux package for the whole thing and couldn't connect my store. I deep dived into https://github.com/bartonhammond/snowflake and got it solved, the snowflake example was really helpful to understand the basics!